# Xcode executes successful build but is unable to launch on a physical device

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm having this exact same issue:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26152

This is on react-native 0.60.4

I'm able to have a successful build in Xcode, but I'm not able launch the app on a physical device.

This is the error that I'm given:
[image]

This is the readout from the console:

```
Details

Unable to launch com.news.arg

Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos

Code: -12

--

Request to launch com.news.arg failed.

Domain: com.apple.dt.deviceprocesscontrolservice

Code: 2

Failure Reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. Application "com.news.arg" is unknown to FrontBoard. : Failed to launch process with bundle identifier 'com.news.arg'.

--

The operation couldn’t be completed. Application "com.news.arg" is unknown to FrontBoard.

Domain: FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain

Code: 4

Failure Reason: Application "com.news.arg" is unknown to FrontBoard.

User Info: {

BSErrorCodeDescription = NotFound;

}

--
```

Someone said on the react native reddit that expo posted a workaround on their twitter, but we were unable to find it when we went back and looked.

Comment: Have you tried running like this : react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6s"

Comment: @mdb this is a physical device; it runs fine in the emulator

Comment: Did  you ever get a resolution to this problem?

Comment: @Chazaq unfortunately, no. I did quite a bit of work looking into this, but never found a resolution. Best of luck.